# Looking for the right MS FrontPage code in listbox

Tags: html, asp-classic, listbox, frontpage

I want to update online amendments on the existing content in a table field (Access database).

For the update syntax I found the necessary (FrontPage) codes here : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240090 (I do use FP 2003)

Before changing a content i want the online-user sees the existing content of the specific field cell and then i will structure the input. Therefore I coded a listbox (combobox):

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="110"><b>Team1:</b></td>
<td width="100"><SELECT name="Team1" size="1" valign="middle">

**<OPTION SELECTED value="<%=FP_FieldHTML(fp_rs,"Team1")%>"></option>**
<option value="John">John</option>
<option value="Joseph">José</option>
<option value="next">next</option>
...
<option value="Alan">Alan</option></select></td></tr>
```

The codeline in bold should display the existing content but I see only a blank box on the screen

Moreover if I want to change a name by a new one, the result in the database is : old name comma(,) new name (expected : only the new name)

Summarized : I am looking for the correct code (cfr. bold)
- to display the existing table cell 
- and to update correct (= delete the old name + input the new one)

Does anyone knows a solution ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-) You can't "bold" text in a code block - if you take a look you'll see the double asterisks (**)  are now in your code. Might be better to write a Comment that starts in ALLCAPS or something like that?

Comment: bold (double asterisks) is the question style - not in the code ;-) Thanks for the reflection.